# What does a multiplier on a component value mean?

Tags: schematics

I have this circuit schematic that shows a `*2` behind the value for `Cin` and `Cout`.
Does the designer mean two capacitors of that value in parallel on the input and output? Is that a common way of doing that? It looks very error prone to me.
([full datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/115/AP3513E-271581.pdf))
[image]

Comment: What datasheet for the device says? Oh, I see it says nothing, you took this pic from the datasheet. Lack of such info is the first sign to withhold using device until clarified by the device manufacturer.

Comment: That sounds to be the most logical explanation: two capacitors of that value in parallel. I have never seen it though in any other datasheet until now.

Comment: Yes, the datasheet is lacking a whole lot of info. Does indeed give a bad impression about the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you use 2 x 22 uF for the output i.e. two 22 uF caps in parallel and for the input you use 2 x 10 uF caps in parallel. It's not commonly used but I have seen it dozens of times at least.

Comment: The sense of it? Backup capacitor if another fails?

Comment: It could be because two caps might be a less expensive way of getting the low value of ESR required.

Comment: Datasheet has nothing about ESR, and no recommendations about cap types. If you noticed its typical application circuit is having input at the right and output at the left, it is unusual. To see the contrast look at the MSX1951 datasheet http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1951-MAX1952.pdf

Comment: That they recommend 2 without specifying a part or type is strange.

Comment: It's a poor data sheet.

Comment: Their application note is better, but surprisingly it does not reassure me.  It would actually make me want to look at alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In [Design Consideration with AP3512E/3E](https://www.diodes.com/assets/App-Note-Files/power/sw_reg/AN1092.pdf), they discuss input and output capacitors.

They do not get into the x2 issue, but the recommended PCB layout shows x2 capacitors on input and output.  Their only acknowledgement is **big value** and **total capacitance**.

Ultimately on input, although they discuss other types, they recommend a big value, high-quality X5R or X7R type dielectric ceramic capacitor

> to filter noise at input voltage source and limit the input ripple voltage

and

> better temperature and voltage characteristics

Output capacitor selection depends output ripple (total capacitance and ESR) and transient response.  They recommend:

> X5R or X7R ceramic dielectric capacitor, or other low ESR tantalum capacitor or aluminum electrolytic capacitor

Lots of design data and recommendations, that is missing in the data sheet, are in Application Note 1092.

Comment: Good, thank you for the link. Now it is clear why the datasheet is poor. The device was developed by the Chinese company *BCD Semiconductor Manufacturing Limited* http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/AP3512E/935208/1, and I am sure Chinese version of datasheet was pretty good. Then BCD was acquired by Diodes Inc with HQ in TX/US, but none cared to improve English datasheets, they just put their logo on it. **This is a shame**.

Comment: @Anonymous It also explains why the schematic is right to left.